# UI Scene Object Reference issue. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a respawn UI, and my player is a prefab. The problem is I need to get a reference of the UI object, but I can't because, you can't reference a scene object in a prefab. I tried other people's advice like make the object you want to reference a prefab, but I can't do that because the object is a UI. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, Here is a simple one:

- Create a Monobehavior Manager script
- Pass all the UI references in it
- Store the Instantiated player object in a variable
- Use getcomponent<> to get players' script
- Pass the UI reference here.